# ReactJS component loses input values entered by the user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a ReactJS component like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {observer} from 'mobx-react'

@observer class InputForm extends React.Component{
    render(){
        if(this.props.store.tab1.isSelected){
            return <form><input type="text"/></form>
        }else if(this.props.store.tab2.isSelected){
            return <form><input type="checkbox"/></form>
        }
    }
}
```

The way this component works: when `tab1` is selected, the component returns a text box in which user can type a text. If `tab2` is selected, the component returns a check-box which user can check.

My problem is that whenever the user switches the tabs from tab1 to tab2 and vice versa, the text which user has entered will be lost or the checkbox will lose its check mark.

I wonder how I can make the text box or the check box preserve their user-entered values when the user switches tabs back and forth.

Comment: the `form` component under each `if` is unmounted, so they lose their state. Store the value of the inputs and update them again when the new component is mounted.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Thanks. I wonder if you can demonstrate with a sample code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the above issue using React + Redux - you're using mobx instead. I briefly looked at the docs (I haven't worked with mobx before), and I think that moving the `<form>` component outside the `if` blocks will fix your issue - something like this https://gist.github.com/tills13/e6c8bd46c53cfd17ec04da6a43f043bc

Comment: I think it's a case of mobx being *too smart*, or perhaps just overly aggressive - I'm not sure.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Thanks. Previously, I was using plain JS and by switching tabs, I was just switching the `display` of the text-box and check-box on and off according to the selected tab. That way, the user-entered values were being preserved when switching tabs back and forth. But now with ReactJS+MobX, the entered values are lost. Which I feel like it makes sense, because every time ReactJS component is rendered, it might actually be destroyed and created from scratch.

Comment: so did my suggestion work?

Comment: @TylerSebastian Yes, when I store the state of an input box in the MobX store, i.e. `this.props.store`, I'm able to re-render input box with the previous state stored in MobX store. However I didn't try the suggested answer by @UG_  in which the state of the component is stored locally not by MobX store. I will try it later.

Comment: Yes that is the idea. You have to store data some where in the state (mobX/redux/react anywhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since react will delete the input dom when rendering checkbox and vice-versa. You will have to store values in state and use them when rendering input or checkbox. Note that below code is suggestive. It might need some more tweaking.

```
@observer class InputForm extends React.Component{
    super() {
        this.state = {value : '', checked : false};
    } 

    onChangeInput (e) { this.setState({value : e.target.value});}
    onChangeCheckbox (e) {this.setState({checked : e.target.checked});} 
    render(){
        if(this.props.store.tab1.isSelected){
            return <form><input onChange=this.onChangeInput.bind(this) type="text" value={this.state.value}/></form>
        }else if(this.props.store.tab2.isSelected){
            return <form><input onChange=this.onChangeChecbox.bind(this) type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked}/></form>
        }
    }
}
```